# Regex: match quotations marks in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to regex and I don't seem te find my way out with those patterns. I'm trying to match the punctuation in a sentence (quotation marks and question mark) with no success.

Here is my code:

```
string sentence = "\"This is the end?\"";
string punctuation = Regex.Match(sentence, "[\"?]").Value;
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'd expect the console to display `"?"`, however, it shows me a double quote.

Comment: Your code prints out a `"` for me (a double quote character), not an empty string. `["?]` means `" OR ?`, so it's matching the starting double quote.

Comment: @canton7 how can I make it match any quote and question mark?

Comment: @TheThugger This one should work `\?\"` or `(\?\")`

Comment: @WaelAbbas still doesn't do the trick. It only matches the quotation mark once.

Comment: you have to iterate over Regex.Matches

Comment: @TheThugger use `Regex.Match("\"This is the?\" end?\"", "(\\?\")+").Groups` and loop throw the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match all quotation marks and question marks as your question states, then your pattern is okay. The problem is that `Regex.Match` will only return the *first* match it finds. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Searches the input string for the *first occurrence* of the specified regular expression...

You probably want to use `Matches`:

```
string sentence = "\"This is the end?\"";
MatchCollection allPunctuation = Regex.Matches(sentence, "[\"?]");

foreach(Match punctuation in allPunctuation)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found {0} at position {1}", punctuation.Value, punctuation.Index);
}
```

This will return:

```
Found " at position 0
Found ? at position 16
Found " at position 17
```

I'd also point out that if you truly want to match *all* punctuation characters, including things like 'French' quotes (`«` and `»`), 'smart' quotes (`“` and `”`), inverted question marks (`¿`), and many others, you can use [Unicode Character categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?view=netframework-4.7.2) with a pattern like `\p{P}`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call Matches instead of Match.

Example:

```
string sentence = "\"This is the end?\"";
var matches = Regex.Matches(sentence, "[\"?]");
var punctuationLocations = string.Empty;
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    punctuationLocations += match.Value + " at index:" + match.Index + Environment.NewLine;
}

// punctuationLocations:
//   " at index:0
//   ? at index:16
//   " at index:17
```